# Setting size for windows that are opened from command line

Tags: python, cmd

I am currently writing a genetic algorithm for airfoil optimization in python, using a program called XFoil for the aerodynamic calculations. The program is run from within the python script using:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull,'w')
ps = sp.Popen(['xfoilP4.exe'],
                  stdin=sp.PIPE,
                  stdout=FNULL,
                  stderr=None)
```

The program XFoil (I only have the .exe, no source code) is calculating aerodynamic properties and opens a window showing them, before closing and starting again for the next iteration. These information pop-up windows that are regularly opened from XFoil (running on command line) are really small. Is there a way to size them (make them larger) in order to monitor the process better? The windows can be resized by hand, but in the iteration procedure where multiple windows open in a short time that takes a long time.

Kind regards.

Comment: You should be able to right click the cmd window and change the size from the properties. The size should be kept across executions.

Comment: Can you show such a window?

Comment: I found some documentation for a program called xfoil that might be yours. It suggests that you can provide a config file to change the plot. Search for 'Start-up Defaults' [here](http://web.mit.edu/aeroutil_v1.0/xfoil_doc.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The window I want to resize is not the cmd window itself, but a window that is opened by the program (XFoil) that is running. I have seen the documentation and used the config file but the values for the plot size only affect the plot lines and not the window size.

Comment: Tried it again with the config file, changing another parameter worked. Thanks a lot, swenzel!!

Comment: @Apollinaris Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)